# How to fix my user login function in php?

Tags: php, symfony

i am setting up my client controller , ( case: connect and connected) the select works with my primary key example select($key) 
 but the select with attributes wont example($login,$password)
even if put correct login and password i get redirected to the login form which

i ive tried changing the sql request and the form inputs

---

a part of model.php

---

```
 public function select($cle_primaire) {
   ** $sql = "SELECT * from ".static::$table." WHERE ".static::$primary."=:cle_primaire";**
    $req_prep = Model::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $req_prep->bindParam(":cle_primaire", $cle_primaire);
    $req_prep->execute();
    $req_prep->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Model'.ucfirst(static::$table));
    if ($req_prep->rowCount()==0){
        return null;
        die();
    }else{
        $rslt = $req_prep->fetch();
        return $rslt;
    }
}
    public function connexion($lg,$pw) {
   ** $sql = "SELECT * from ".static::$table." WHERE ".static::$login."=:lg AND".static::$password."=:pw";**
    $req_prep = Model::$pdo->prepare($sql);
    $req_prep->bindParam(":lg", $lg);
    $req_prep->bindParam(":pw", $pw);
    $req_prep->execute();
    $req_prep->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Model'.ucfirst(static::$table));
    if ($req_prep->rowCount()==0){
        return null;
        die();
    }else{
        $rslt = $req_prep->fetch();
        return $rslt;
    }    
}
```

---

a part of modelclient.php

---

```
 require_once ("Model.php"); 

class ModelClient extends Model{

 private $cin;
  private $clientname;
  private $clientemail;
   private $clientpw;
   private $tel;
    private $adress;

   protected static $table = 'client';
   protected static $primary = 'cin';
    protected static $login = 'clientemail';
   protected static $password = 'clientpw';
```

---

a part of controllerclient

---

```
 case "connect":
    $pagetitle = "login ";
    $view = "login";
    require ("{$ROOT}{$DS}view{$DS}view.php");
    break;


    case"connected":
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lg']) && isset($_REQUEST['pw'])){
        $lg = $_REQUEST["lg"];
        $pw = md5($_REQUEST["pw"]);
    $cnx=ModelClient::connexion($lg,$pw);
    }
    if($cnx!=null){
    $pagetitle = "logged in  ";
    $view = "interface";
    require ("{$ROOT}{$DS}view{$DS}view.php");    
    }
    else
    $pagetitle = "login ";
    $view="login";
            require ("{$ROOT}{$DS}view{$DS}view.php");    
    break;
```

running out of time

Comment: it think if you use fosUserBundle would be faster and better for you.https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

Comment: @A.Marwan Leaving aside the rather dubious merits of using the FOSUserBundle, the fact that the poster is not even using Symfony at all will make it particularly challenging.

Comment: @Cerad the poster used the symfony tag, plus checking the fosuserbundle source code can help with the problem.

Comment: @A.Marwan The poster has a total of 6 reps.  It is easy to determine that they added the symfony tag simply because they considered symfony to be the same as mvc.  Look at the posted code.  It's all old style procedural stuff riddled with sql injections.  Probably copied from some long defunct tutorial.  Or maybe a class assignment.  Not exactly Symfony.  And looking at the FOSUserBundle source code is not going to help anybody at all.